# AngularJS $http.POST method 405 error

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

In $http.post method I'm getting 405 issue. We are using single service(REST) for both POST & GET methods.

if url having localhost it is working. urlAddScenario is localhost/Service.svc/api/scenarios/add. If I'm using machine name instead of locahost it is not working. machinname/Service.svc/api/scenarios/add

My JS code is

```
 scenarioExecutionFactory.addScenario = function (scenarioId) {
        return $http.post(urlAddScenario, scenarioId)               
    };
```

anotherJS:

```
 var runScenarioId = { "ScenarioId": 10 }
                   scenarioExecutionFactory.addScenario(runScenarioId )
                         .success(function (data) {
                             $scope.getScenarioRecentRuns($scope.CurrentScenario);
                         });
```

WCF Service:

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "api/scenarios/add",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            Method = "POST")]
        Request AddScenario(ScenarioRequestParams requestParams);
```

config:

```
   <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Ellucian-Media-Type" />
  </customHeaders>

</httpProtocol>
```

I'm seeing OPTIONS instead of POST in Headers.

Headers:

```
**OPTIONS** http://ddd/HelloService/HelloService.svc/PostData HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:31284
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: vijayakatta
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

Error:

IE: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load htp//machinename/services.svc/api/scenarios/add. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Response Headers: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Check the answer to this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528634/ajax-post-works-vs-angularjs-http-does-not-work-w-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 6):

In order to enable `CORS` via `web.config` properly you need to specify these 3 custom headers

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

If you plan to support `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs you also need to handle the **preflight** check.
You can read more about `CORS` and *preflight check* in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27374066/4304188

Comment: What's your definition for ScenarioRequestParams? My guess is that you're construction your post request in the wrong manner.

Comment: Are you truly using WeB API, because you have posted code from an ASMX web service.

Comment: param is  "ScenarioId": 10, it is not issue with request param. I've tested POST scenario in fiddler it is working good. Some how it is not working from application.

Comment: Are you configuring CORS via configuration as well? If not you should remove that. Other than that your Web API looks like. The problem should be in your firewall.

Comment: That web.config section I posted should be enough.

Comment: Do you mean this <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> setting. Already added.

Comment: Yes I added   <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Ellucian-Media-Type" />
      </customHeaders>

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$http({
    url: "",
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param({
        data1: ""       
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});
```

I was also facing this issue. Was getting 405 and OPTIONS was made. I came across a blog and found that the way angular encodes param is not understood by web server properly. So, jQuery is required to encode POST data

Answer (score 0):

Mistake on my part, I simply had to *remove* `method="post" action=""`

Bad:
`<form ng-submit="doSubmit()" name="myform" method="post" action="" role="form">`

Good:
`<form ng-submit="doSubmit()" name="myform" role="form">`