# AngularJs giving me status 405 method not found error on calling webservice

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angularJS and learning implementing webservices. I have a sevice that I hit on 'Post man ' that is working fine but when I am implementing this service in my angular code and i tested on Google chrome console it is giving me status 405 method not found error. I don't know the reason.Below is the code I am using

```
var myApp = angular
            .module('myApp',[])
            .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {


            var parameter = JSON.stringify({search:''});
            $http.post(url, parameter).then(function(response) {
                alert(response.data);
            });
});
```

[image: Attached is the error image]

Comment: Is this of any help to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387467/angularjs-http-post-method-405-error

Comment: no, it is not working for me